# Transpose dictionary key longer 255 in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I need to write in different columns in the excel sheet the data (like sender, receive date, Subject,...) of many outlook emails. I am able to do it reporting each email data in the corresponding cell, but the performance is quite slow. My idea is to store emails' data into a dictionary (dic) keys and then transpose these data into the excel sheet. The problem is that the dictionary keys are longer than 255 and transpose does not work.
I tried to use an array as variant and convert the array into strings, but I am not really expert and I failed. Could you please help to adjust the code so that I can transpose the key in the excel sheet (I will add the text to column function to split key values into different columns)

```
Sub List_Email_Info()

Dim xlApp As excel.Application
Dim xlWB As excel.Workbook
Dim xlfoldWS, xlWS As excel.Worksheet
Dim wb As Object
Dim Xl As Object
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim dic As Object
Dim OutRecipients As Object
Dim i As Long ' Row tracker
Dim arrHeader As Variant
Dim olNS As NameSpace
Dim olInboxFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim olItems As Object
Dim olMailItem As Object

arrHeader = Array("#", "Date Created", "Subject", "ConversationID", "Sender's Name", "Receiver", "Copy to", "Category", "Country")

On Error Resume Next

On Error Resume Next
Set Xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Excel is not running"
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Set wb = Xl.Workbooks("MTR.xlsx")
If wb Is Nothing Then
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\MTR.xlsx")
    GoTo lbl_Exit
End If

Set olNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")

wb.Activate

Set xlfoldWS = wb.Worksheets("outlook folder and date")
folr = xlfoldWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(folr, 1))

foldstr = cell.Text
oFolderstr = Cells(cell.Row, 2).Text
Dim olFolder As Folder

For Each Folder In olNS.Folders
If InStr(Folder, foldstr) > 0 Then
Set olFolder = Folder

 For i = olFolder.Folders.Count To 1 Step -1
 Set oFolder = olFolder.Folders(i)
 If Folder & "-" & oFolder = cell.Offset(, 2).Text Then

Set olItems = oFolder.Items
 olItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True


w = 1

On Error Resume Next

wb.Activate
Set xlWS = wb.Worksheets("MTR")

If wb.Worksheets("MTR").Range("A1") = "" Then

wb.Worksheets("MTR").Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arrHeader) + 1).Value = arrHeader
End If

lr = xlWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

w = lr
s = 1
c = 0

Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

For Each olMailItem In olItems

dic.Add s & "|" & olItems(s).ReceivedTime & "|" & olItems(s).ConversationID & "|" &     olItems(s).SenderName & "|" & olItems(s).To & "|" & olItems(s).CC & "|" & olItems(s).Categories, ""

' xlW.Cells(w + 1, "A").Value = olItems(s).ReceivedTime
'xlW.Cells(w + 1, "B").Value = olItems(s).Subject
' xlW.Cells(w + 1, "C").Value = olItems(s).ConversationID
' xlW.Cells(w + 1, "D").Value = olItems(s).SenderName
' xlW.Cells(w + 1, "E").Value = olItems(s).To
'xlW.Cells(w + 1, "F").Value = olItems(s).CC
'xlW.Cells(w + 1, "G").Value = olItems(s).Categories


s = s + 1
w = w + 1


Next olMailItem
nextfolder:

xlWS.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(dic.Keys), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dic.Keys)

xlWS.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit


End If


Next
End If

Next
Next cell
MsgBox "Export complete.", vbInformation
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

Set olItems = Nothing
Set olFolder = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing

lbl_Exit:
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: why stuff everything into 1 key. Create a loop that makes a dictionary *for each item in the email*, then write that dictionary list into the cells after. For example `d.Add "Recieved Time", olItems(s).ReceivedTime` if you want to loop all outlook at once, you can make a dictionary of dictionaries and loop them at the end.

Comment: So the issue is you run out of columns?

Comment: Use array instead of dictionary.

Comment: The issue is the length of the key that can be longer than 255 char. The same in case of array. No values are written into the sheet. I'ill try with Scott's suggestion.

Comment: Why do you have `Dim xlApp As excel.Application` and `Dim Xl As Object`?  In my view, using a Dictionary just adds to the duration since you have to move data from Outlook to Dictionary to Excel instead of direct from Outlook to Excel.  Simply adding `xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False` will reduce the duration significantly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to shift columns to rows.  Is that right?  There are so many ways to do this.  I feel like I need more info to make a fully informed decision.  Please show a before & after screen shot of what you are trying to do.  In the meantime, feel free to try the small script below.  Hopefully it does what you want, basically, or it gets you closer to your goal.

```
Sub CombineColumns1()
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim xNextRow As Long
    Dim xTxt As String
    On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveSheet
        xTxt = .RangeSelection.Address
        Set xRng = Application.InputBox("please select the data range", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
        If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        j = xRng.Columns(1).Column
        For i = 4 To xRng.Columns.Count Step 3
            'Need to recalculate the last row, as some of the final columns may not have data in all rows
            xNextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            .Range(xRng.Cells(1, i), xRng.Cells(xRng.Rows.Count, i + 2)).Copy .Cells(xNextRow, j)
            .Range(xRng.Cells(1, i), xRng.Cells(xRng.Rows.Count, i + 2)).Clear
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following Scott I revised the code using dictionary and collection
I post here the part of my code related to the collection solution for anyone they might find it useful

```
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
Dim omail As clsomail
Dim coll As Collection
Dim key As Variant



w = 1

On Error Resume Next

Xlwb.Activate
Set xlWS = Xlwb.Worksheets("MTR")

If Xlwb.Worksheets(excelfilename).Range("A1") = "" Then
Xlwb.Worksheets(excelfilename).Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arrHeader) + 1).Value = arrHeader
End If
lr = xlWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

w = lr

For Each olMailItem In olItems

If olMailItem.Class = olMail Then


Set coll = New Collection
dic.Add d, coll

Set omail = New clsomail

clsomail.d = d
omail.Rec = olMailItem.ReceivedTime
omail.Subj = olMailItem.Subject
omail.Con = olMailItem.ConversationID
omail.Send = olMailItem.SenderName
omail.ToA = olMailItem.To
omail.CC = olMailItem.CC
omail.Cat = olMailItem.Categories

coll.Add omail

d = d + 1

End If

Next olMailItem


i = 2
For Each key In dic
xlWS.Cells(i, 1) = key
Set coll = dic(key)


For Each omail In coll


xlWS.Cells(i, 2) = CDate(omail.Rec)
xlWS.Cells(i, 3) = omail.Subj
xlWS.Cells(i, 4) = omail.Con
xlWS.Cells(i, 5) = omail.Send
xlWS.Cells(i, 6) = omail.ToA
xlWS.Cells(i, 7) = omail.CC
xlWS.Cells(i, 8) = omail.Cat



i = i + 1
Next omail

Next
Set coll = Nothing
Set omail = Nothing
```

I used a class module to define the type of data

```
Public s As Long
Public Rec As String
Public Subj As String
Public Con As String
Public Send As String
Public ToA As String
Public CC As String
Public Cat As String
Public Cou As String
```

here two useful links

https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/
https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/